# Scala syntax inquiry, return type inference

Tags: scala

Code seems trivial but I'm not understanding one thing in the return value:

```
trait JdbcTemplate {
  def query(psc: PreparedStatementCreator,
            rowMapper: RowMapper): List[_]
}
```

What exactly does `List[_]` mean here? Wouldn't using `List[Any]` imply the same thing? Where can I read on the differences?

Answer (score 2):

`Any` is a specific, known (though utterly all-inclusive) type. The use of the underscore as type parameter is a shorthand for a more cumbersome and more general syntax for what is called an "existential type." Existential types are non-specific: They say there's at least one type that could go here. They are the dual of universal quantification that is the interpretation of the more commonly used unbounded type parameters. E.g., `def method[T](t: T) ...`. In this construct, `T` may be bound to any type whatsoever though at each place where that type is instantiated (every occurrence of a call to that method), it is bound to a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `_` means you don't care about the type and [`Any` is supertype of everything](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128), both are the same.